# Вопрос по Applescript

Tags: mac, applescript

Решил поиграться с applescript. Первое полезно, что решил написать: скрипт, который по комбинации клавиш ставит/убирает галочку в настройках. Если конкретно, то галочка "Использование клавиш F1, F2, ... как стандартные функциональные клавиши". Задался вопросом: как достать этот TRUE/FALSE и откуда? Вероятно какой-то plist или, возможно, можно как-то доступиться к этой настройке при помощи

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell keyboard preferences
        get properties (*...
        .....*)
    end tell
end tell
```

И, если можно, ссылочку бы какую для предотвращения последующих вопросов такого рода. Спасибо

Comment: На просторах интернета нашел [ссылочку](http://www.macworld.com/article/1157370/applescriptsystempreferences.html) Встал очередной вопрос: откуда автор узнал подробности такого рода: 

    `click checkbox 1 of row 11 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1`

Если кто-то знает источник - был бы жутко рад увидеть.

Comment: Отвечая самому себе на предыдущий комментарий: [ссылка](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) на прекрасную утилитку, помогающую в этой самой навигации по каркасу Cocoa (поправьте, если неправильно понял по чему навигация).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился. Привожу код скрипта для вышеописанного действия.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            tell window 1
                tell scroll area 1
                    click button 11
                end tell
            end tell
            tell window 1
                tell tab group 1
                    click radio button 1
                    click checkbox 1
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Оказалось все довольно просто. Пользовался приятной утилитой [UIBrowser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/), также [вот](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html) полезная ссылка. Осталось навесить этот скрипт на некий шорткат. [Вот](http://veritrope.com/the-basics-using-keyboard-shortcuts-with-applescripts/) полезная ссылка по этому поводу. Делал это при помощи стандартной утилиты [Automator](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator). Получилось слегка не то, что хотел, но как есть. Если получится иначе - дополню.